# Pandas filtering giving some weird results

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm looking at some weather data, and it contains a figure for hourly precipitation. I'm trying to sort out the entries that contain precipitation > 0 (it ranges from 0 to around 0.4).

I assumed I could get these by just doing `weather[weather.HourlyPrecip > 0]` (`weather` is a DataFrame here), but apparently I was wrong:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
weather[weather.HourlyPrecip > 0].HourlyPrecip.resample('1D', how='sum').plot(ax=axes[0,0]); axes[0,0].set_title('>0')
weather[weather.HourlyPrecip >= 0].HourlyPrecip.resample('1D', how='sum').plot(ax=axes[1,0]); axes[1,0].set_title('>=0')
weather[weather.HourlyPrecip == 0].HourlyPrecip.resample('1D', how='sum').plot(ax=axes[0,1]); axes[0,1].set_title('==0')
weather.HourlyPrecip.resample('1D', how='sum').plot(ax=axes[1,1]); axes[1,1].set_title('all')
```

...yields...

[image: chart]

What's going on here?

---

UPDATE: Here's a rough idea of what the data looks like:

```
In [215]: weather.HourlyPrecip
Out[215]: Date_Time
          2013-12-01 00:51:00    0
          2013-12-01 01:20:00    0
          2013-12-01 01:51:00    0
          2013-12-01 02:51:00    0
          2013-12-01 03:10:00    0
          2013-12-01 03:49:00    0
          2013-12-01 03:51:00    0
          2013-12-01 04:25:00    0
          2013-12-01 04:35:00    0
          2013-12-01 04:51:00    0
          2013-12-01 05:51:00    0
          2013-12-01 06:00:00    0
          2013-12-01 06:09:00    0
          2013-12-01 06:40:00    0
          2013-12-01 06:51:00    0
          ...
          2013-12-31 09:51:00    0
          2013-12-31 10:51:00    0
          2013-12-31 11:51:00    0
          2013-12-31 12:51:00    0
          2013-12-31 13:51:00    0
          2013-12-31 14:51:00    0
          2013-12-31 15:51:00    0
          2013-12-31 16:51:00    0
          2013-12-31 17:51:00    0
          2013-12-31 18:51:00    0
          2013-12-31 19:51:00    0
          2013-12-31 20:51:00    0
          2013-12-31 21:51:00    0
          2013-12-31 22:51:00    0
          2013-12-31 23:51:00    0
          Name: HourlyPrecip, Length: 1018
```

And all the values:

```
In [216]: np.unique(weather.HourlyPrecip.ravel())
Out[216]: array([ 0.  ,  0.01,  0.02,  0.03,  0.04,  0.05,  0.06,  0.07,  0.08,
          0.09,  0.1 ,  0.12,  0.13,  0.19,  0.2 ,  0.23,  0.24,  0.28,  0.38])
```

(The column is all floats.)

Comment: Please provide some sample data for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your initial assumption is correct: `df[df.precip > 0]` does work. it's your testing that's flawed. when you resample, you're ending up with a bunch of `np.nan` values when there is no hourly data for the day. so when you plot it, it looks disjointed.

try using something like: `resampled_data.fillna(0).plot()` and i think you'll see what you're expecting.

Comment: Oh, I see. So, since the line graph doesn't show isolated points, I'm only seeing anything where consecutive days had precipitation?